# convert Hexadecimal to text (ASCII) or JSON object in Node.js (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, hex, ascii

I am receiving Hexadecimal from hardware and trying to convert it to json object using Node.js (Javascript)

Received data

```
50 4F 53 54 20 2F 77 69 66 69 20 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 0D 0A 48 6F 73 74 3A 20 35 32 2E 31 35 2E 36 34 2E 33 34 3A 38 30 38 30 0D 0A 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 2D 54 79 70 65 3A 61 70 70 6C 69 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 2F 6A 73 6F 6E 3B 20 63 68 61 72 73 65 74 3D 75 74 66 2D 38 0D 0A 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 2D 4C 65 6E 67 74 68 3A 20 38 33 35 0D 0A 0D 0A 7B 22 72 6F 75 74 65 5F 6D 61 63 22 3A 22 46 43 35 39 36 37 33 36 44 46 32 33 22 2C 22 64 65 76 69 63 65 73 22 3A 5B 7B 22 6D 61 63 22 3A 22 34 34 34 42 39 41 36 43 35 43 38 38 22 2C 22 64 61 74 61 22 3A 22 30 32 30 31 31 41 30 41 46 46 34 43 30 30 31 30 30 35 30 42 31 30 43 39 30 39 41 42 22 2C 22 72 73 73 69 22 3A 2D 33 35 7D 2C 7B 22 6D 61 63 22 3A 22 30 38 44 46 31 46 39 39 46 38 42 37 22 2C 22 64 61 74 61 22 3A 22 30 32 30 31 30 32 30 33 30 33 42 45 46 45 30 44 46 46 31 30 30 31 34 30 30 43 30 31 34 31 46 34 35 43 38 39 41 45 34 43 31 45 22 2C 22 72 73 73 69 22 3A 2D 36 35 7D 2C 7B 22 6D 61 63 22 3A 22 44 37 32 42 44 36 45 35 39 44 46 35 22 2C 22 64 61 74 61 22 3A 22 30 32 30 31 30 36 31 41 46 46 34 43 30 30 30 32 31 35 46 37 38 32 36 44 41 36 34 46 41 32 34 45 39 38 38 30 32 34 42 43 35 42 37 31 45 30 38 39 33 45 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 42 33 22 2C 22 72 73 73 69 22 3A 2D 38 31 7D 2C 7B 22 6D 61 63 22 3A 22 44 38 34 36 39 34 31 39 31 30 34 36 22 2C 22 64 61 74 61 22 3A 22 30 32 30 31 30 34 31 42 46 46 34 43 30 30 30 32 31 35 45 42 45 46 44 30 38 33 37 30 41 32 34 37 43 38 39 38 33 37 45 37 42 35 36 33 34 44 46 35 32 34 31 31 31 31 30 30 30 30 43 35 35 44 22 2C 22 72 73 73 69 22 3A 2D 33 34 7D 2C 7B 22 6D 61 63 22 3A 22 44 39 36 30 41 44 44 38 30 43 33 37 22 2C 22 64 61 74 61 22 3A 22 30 32 30 31 30 34 31 42 46 46 34 43 30 30 30 32 31 35 45 42 45 46 44 30 38 33 37 30 41 32 34 37 43 38 39 38 33 37 45 37 42 35 36 33 34 44 46 35 32 34 44 38 41 44 45 37 30 43 43 42 35 45 22 2C 22 72 73 73 69 22 3A 2D 33 30 7D 2C 7B 22 6D 61 63 22 3A 22 44 35 46 32 46 43 32 36 31 38 39 45 22 2C 22 64 61 74 61 22 3A 22 30 32 30 31 30 35 30 32 30 41 30 30 30 33 30 33 45 37 46 45 30 39 46 46 34 45 41 42 44 35 46 32 46 43 32 36 31 38 39 45 30 35 30 39 34 38 35 37 33 30 33 31 22 2C 22 72 73 73 69 22 3A 2D 37 39 7D 2C 7B 22 6D 61 63 22 3A 22 43 46 39 43 44 44 36 38 46 33 44 46 22 2C 22 64 61 74 61 22 3A 22 30 32 30 31 30 34 31 42 46 46 34 43 30 30 30 32 31 35 45 42 45 46 44 30 38 33 37 30 41 32 34 37 43 38 39 38 33 37 45 37 42 35 36 33 34 44 46 35 32 34 31 31 31 31 45 30 30 30 43 35 35 43 22 2C 22 72 73 73 69 22 3A 2D 33 35 7D 2C 7B 22 6D 61 63 22 3A 22 43 37 34 30 36 42 34 34 36 38 33 30 22 2C 22 64 61 74 61 22 3A 22 30 32 30 31 30 34 31 42 46 46 34 43 30 30 30 32 31 35 45 42 45 46 44 30 38 33 37 30 41 32 34 37 43 38 39 38 33 37 45 37 42 35 36 33 34 44 46 35 32 34 31 31 31 31 45 30 30 30 43 35 35 45 22 2C 22 72 73 73 69 22 3A 2D 34 30 7D 5D 2C 22 61 6C 6C 43 6F 75 6E 74 22 3A 38 7D 0D 0A 0D 0A
```

I tried this and some others way But not getting expected output

```
function hex2a(hexx) {
var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
var str = '';
for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
    str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
return str;}
```

if I am using [ascii to text converter](https://www.fireboxtools.com/text-tools/ascii-to-string) then receiving proper output.

Which is

> POST /wifi HTTP/1.1
> Host: 52.15.64.34:8080
> Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
> Content-Length: 835

> {"route_mac":"FC596736DF23","devices":[{"mac":"444B9A6C5C88","data":"02011A0AFF4C0010050B10C909AB","rssi":-35},{"mac":"08DF1F99F8B7","data":"0201020303BEFE0DFF1001400C0141F45C89AE4C1E","rssi":-65},{"mac":"D72BD6E59DF5","data":"0201061AFF4C000215F7826DA64FA24E988024BC5B71E0893E12345678B3","rssi":-81},{"mac":"D84694191046","data":"0201041BFF4C000215EBEFD08370A247C89837E7B5634DF52411110000C55D","rssi":-34},{"mac":"D960ADD80C37","data":"0201041BFF4C000215EBEFD08370A247C89837E7B5634DF524D8ADE70CCB5E","rssi":-30},{"mac":"D5F2FC26189E","data":"020105020A000303E7FE09FF4EABD5F2FC26189E050948573031","rssi":-79},{"mac":"CF9CDD68F3DF","data":"0201041BFF4C000215EBEFD08370A247C89837E7B5634DF5241111E000C55C","rssi":-35},{"mac":"C7406B446830","data":"0201041BFF4C000215EBEFD08370A247C89837E7B5634DF5241111E000C55E","rssi":-40}],"allCount":8}

Comment: is data a string? please add a small pice of data in the original formatting.

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: @Richard I am getting some random ascii characters

Comment: @NinaScholz i already mentioned data. That is string.

Comment: it looks like there are spaces in the string and you didn't account for it. And if it is already a string, why call "toString" on it?

Comment: no, you took something, is it with spaces?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Thanks

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should firstly remove spaces from your HEX string:

```
str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

After that you can use your function.